# Type stability with container types and matrix-vector multiply in Julia

Tags: julia, matrix-multiplication, type-stability

I am trying to use Julia's `A_mul_B!` with a container type, something like

```
# my composite type, contains 2 vectors and 1 matrix of same Float type
type MyContainer{T <: Float}
    z :: Vector
    x :: Matrix
    y :: Vector
    MyContainer(z::Vector{T}, x::Matrix{T}, y::Vector{T}) = new(z,x,y) 
end
```

I then use an instance of `MyContainer` with `A_mul_B!` followed by some arithmetic with the `Vector` objects:

```
# only work with single/double precision
typealias Float Union{Float32, Float64}

# function to perform mat-vec multiply
function f{T <: Float}(v::MyContainer{T}) 
    Base.A_mul_B!(v.z, v.x, v.y)
    return sumabs2(v.z) * sumabs2(v.y)
end
```

As defined, `f` is curiously not type-stable, even though the constructor itself is type-stable. Is there a place where I can annotate the types of `z`, `x`, and `y` so that `A_mul_B!` sees them?

Here is a minimal working example:

#### MyModule.jl

```
module MyModule

export MyContainer, f

# only work with single/double precision
typealias Float Union{Float32, Float64}

# my composite type, contains 2 vectors and 1 matrix of same Float type
type MyContainer{T <: Float}
    z :: Vector
    x :: Matrix
    y :: Vector
    MyContainer(z::Vector{T}, x::Matrix{T}, y::Vector{T}) = new(z,x,y) 
end

# testing routine initializes all arrays with a single value 
function MyContainer{T <: Float}(n::Int, t::T)
    z = t*ones(T, n)
    x = t*ones(T, (n,n))
    y = t*ones(T, n)
    return MyContainer{eltype(z)}(z, x, y)
end

# function to perform mat-vec multiply
function f{T <: Float}(v::MyContainer{T}) 
    Base.A_mul_B!(v.z, v.x, v.y)
    return sumabs2(v.z) * sumabs2(v.y)
end

end
```

#### test.jl

```
include("MyModule.jl")

function g() 
    # check type stability
    @code_warntype MyModule.MyContainer(10, 1.0) # type-stable
    @code_warntype MyModule.f(v) # red Array{T,1}, Array{T,2}, Any

    # make a container
    v = MyModule.MyContainer(10, 1.0)

    # does type-stability matter for performance?
    @time 1+1 
    MyModule.f(v)
    @time MyModule.f(v) # maybe... note small memory allocation
end

g()
```

#### partial output

```
# omit output of @code_warntype for conciseness
  0.000000 seconds
  0.000001 seconds (3 allocations: 48 bytes)
10000.0
```

Comment: Another detail: if I wrap `A_mul_B!` in another function typed on an instance of `MyContainer{T}`, then the type instability remains. In other words, `q{T <: Float}(v::MyContainer{T}) = A_mul_B!(v.z, v.x, v.y)` adds no stability.

Comment: The type definition itself is a cause of trouble - all fields should be concrete types, e.g. Vector{T},  for good performance.

Comment: That seems to do the trick.

A corollary question: in my own code, I followed the example from the Julia [performance tips](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/#avoid-fields-with-abstract-containers). You will observe that the bitstype is absent from the field declaration. Is that because the field declares an abstract array type *and* a bitstype?

Comment: @KevinLKeys If I understand you correctly, you mean to ask why `T <: AbstractArray` suffices, and we don't need `T, U <: AbstractArray{T}`? This is because `AbstractArray` is an abstract type for which e.g. `Array{Int, 1}` is a subtype. In fact, the latter syntax `T, U <: AbstractArray{T}` is not currently supported in Julia.

Comment: Thank you @FengyangWang, but I was asking about why the example uses

    type MyContainer{T, A<:AbstractVector}
        a::A
    end

and not

    type MyContainer{T, A<:AbstractVector}
        a::A{T} # or AbstractVector{T}
    end

My reason for asking is that I assumed that I needed to use `Vector` instead of `Vector{T}` in `MyContainer`. @DavidP.Sanders argued correctly that this  setup yields suboptimal performance.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear—that is precisely what I was trying to answer. `Array{Int, 1}` (or `Vector{Int}`, in other words) _is_ a subtype of `AbstractVector`, so it is a valid value for type parameter `A` in `MyContainer{A <: AbstractVector}`.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you @FengyangWang!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David Sanders pointed out, the problem is

```
type MyContainer{T <: Float}
    z :: Vector
    x :: Matrix
    y :: Vector
    MyContainer(z::Vector{T}, x::Matrix{T}, y::Vector{T}) = new(z,x,y) 
end
```

Since `Vector` and `Matrix` are abstract types, this type's fields are not concrete-inferrable. The fix is to concretely type them:

```
type MyContainer{T <: Float}
    z :: Vector{T}
    x :: Matrix{T}
    y :: Vector{T}
end
```

Comment: Note that the inner constructor is unnecessary.

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders Thanks. As this is a community wiki post, I encourage you to edit it to fix any other issues.